# Widget Pending Intent won't work after application is Force Stopped/Killed

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

I have a widget that is a part of my main app. Usually when the app is updated, a PendingIntent is created that takes the user to an Activity in the main app when the widget is clicked. However, when the main app is force stopped or killed by the OS because of an error, the widget stops responding when it is clicked. I believe it also stops receiving broadcasts because the onReceive method is not being called.

Here is what I have in the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".widgets.AppWidget" android:label="@string/widget_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
        <action android:name="com.myApp.android.widgets.CLICK.start"></action>
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                     android:resource="@xml/appWidget_provider"/>
</receiver>
```

The widget code is in a separate package from the main app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, when the main app is force stopped or killed by the OS because of an error, the widget stops responding when it is clicked. I believe it also stops receiving broadcasts because the onReceive method is not being called.

On Android 3.1+, your app widget will definitely stop working if the user force-closes you, until the user manually launches one of your activities by other means (e.g., home screen launcher).

However, "killed by the OS because of an error" should not have this effect AFAIK. If you can create a reproducible test case that demonstrates this, post it somewhere so we can examine it.

Comment: Thank you! I tried it on an older phone and it did indeed work. I noticed once that my app was shut down by the OS because of an error and then the widget stopped working. I haven't been able to recreate it since but I will keep an eye out for it again.

Comment: We're having the same issue. It seems to happen on Lollipop but it works on Kit Kat. Any explanation? Is there something we can set with the intents that helps this?

Comment: @RCB: "Any explanation?" -- nothing other than what is in my answer. "Is there something we can set with the intents that helps this?" -- I doubt it. As I wrote three years ago, "if you can create a reproducible test case that demonstrates this, post it somewhere so we can examine it."

Comment: To add some more comments, there is difference in how different task managers kill an app. Some tests show that when using apps from the app store to kill another app, the widgets still work as expected, whereas when using more "native", manufacturer provided task managers (like some devices have available through System Settings > App manager) the widget is considered `user force-closed` as specified in CommonsWare answer. This difference can also be seen when closing an app through an app the system app manager still considers it to be running and available for closing.