# Will android Log work after app is force stopped

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

I have one simple doubt,
In android studio we see logs in Logcat. I am using this library for logs

```
android.util.Log
```

So my question is will I be able to see my Application logs, if I force stop app( long press->App info->force stop)?

I am trying to create widget which should run even after force stop.

Comment: Nothing runs after a force stop.  When you force stop it, the process is killed and cannot be restarted until a user does so manually.

Comment: As for logs that were written before a force stop-  those will still be in logcat, but logcat itself is not a permanent storage solution-  it has a fixed size and older entries are overwritten as data is added.  It's also a shared log across all apps on the phone (as well as the OS itself).  So it won't be around in there very long.

Comment: Related: [Where will code stop running when app is killed from task manager on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33760252/208273), as well as [this answer on what happens to widgets after a force stop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11267773/208273).